# Hierarchical Queries in H2

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I have the following query, which works fine in [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/index.html):

```
SELECT ID
FROM PEOPLE
  START WITH ID = <person_id> 
  CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID;
```

This works on a self-referencing table, which contains people. It finds the ids of all ancestors of a person.

The issue is that I need this query to also work in [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), but [H2 does not support `CONNECT BY PRIOR`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/GjfTo81L0bQ). Therefore, **how can I rewrite the above query so that it works with both Oracle and H2?**

Comment: http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries

Comment: Thanks, I've found out about them a few minutes after posting the question. I've now added a solution that uses recursive queries.

Comment: Although I've posted a solution, I'm still interested in more optimal solutions so please post them if there are any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using [recursive queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression), which are supported by both [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_recursive_subquery_factoring_with_clause.htm) and [H2](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries):

```
WITH ancestors(ID, PARENT_ID) AS 
(
  SELECT ID, PARENT_ID FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID = <person_id>
    UNION ALL
  SELECT S2.ID, S2.SCHEDULE_PARENT_ID FROM ancestors S1 INNER JOIN EFP.COLLATERAL_SCHEDULE S2 ON S1.SCHEDULE_PARENT_ID = S2.ID
)
SELECT ID FROM ancestors;
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there a way to convert this to a view so that it lists all ancestry, not just the one for ID = <person_id>?

Comment: @DavidBrossard: You could use instead of `ID =` rather something like `ID in select id from people`. But take into account that in this case you need to have a clear anchor what each row represents.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do a normal inner join to the same table.

```
SELECT parent.id
FROM PEOPLE parent
inner join PEOPLE child on child.parent_id = parent.id
where child.person_id = {ID}
```

Comment: That doesn't return any rows. Also, SELECT ID is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, but this query only returns the parent of the child, not all the ancestors...

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki yeah just realized that - you don't have many options I'm afraid. I think some of your logic will have to remain untested! Unless you know how many levels of ancestry you are interested in, in which case you can just add multple joins. Or try rewriting using a common table expression.